# error: no matching package named `rocket_dyn_templates` found

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-rocket

I'm trying to build a small web server using Rust and the Rocket framework. For this I need the `rocket_dyn_templates` crate, so I did a `cargo search rocket_dyn_templates`, which gave as output

```
rocket_dyn_templates = "0.1.0-rc.2"    # Dynamic templating engine integration for Rocket.
```

and added

```
rocket_dyn_templates = "0.1.0-rc2"
```

to the Cargo.toml file in my project.

However, when I try `cargo run`, `cargo update` or `cargo package` I always get the same output:

```
   Updating crates.io index
error: no matching package named `rocket_dyn_templates` found
location searched: registry `crates-io`
required by package `calc v0.1.0 (/home/utilisateur/tmp/calc)`
```

I was expecting the crate to be found and downloaded, instead I keep getting the error message that no matching package was found. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Aside: instead of manually adding you could have done `cargo add rocket_dyn_templates`

Comment: you're missing a . in the `.toml` it's `rc.2` not `rc2`

Comment: You may want `features = ["handlebars", "tera"]` as well. The [documentation](https://crates.io/crates/rocket_dyn_templates) is pretty good.

Comment: thank you for the replies, adding the `.` to make it `rc.2` instead of `rc2` in the Cargo.toml file fixed the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

As cafce25 said, the issue was a missing `.` in the `Cargo.toml` file - it should be `rc.2`, not `rc2`.